Tried to manually add a slideshow, now my user crashes
I was attempting to follow this tutorial to create a background slideshow (https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/09/desktop-wallpaper-slideshow-ubuntu-20-04/). I finished creating the xml files, and I believe I selected the slideshow I had just made from the setting GUI. My desktop then went black, then I got an error message telling me something was wrong, to log out and try again later. I pressed the log out button, attempted to log back in, and was greeted with a black screen for a few moments before getting the same error message. How would I go about resetting my background settings? I have another user on the machine, so I can use the terminal to make any settings edits.
